# Cannot load file containing pickled data - Python .npy I/O

Tags: python, numpy, io

I am trying to save a dataframe and a matrix as .npy files with np.save() and then read them using np.load() but I get the following error:

```
  File "/Users/sofiafarina/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 457, in load
    raise ValueError("Cannot load file containing pickled data "

ValueError: Cannot load file containing pickled data when allow_pickle=False
```

Even if I write allow_pickle=True I get an error:

```
  File "/Users/sofiafarina/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 463, in load
    "Failed to interpret file %s as a pickle" % repr(file))

OSError: Failed to interpret file 'finaldf_p_85_12.npy' as a pickle
```

So how could I save a df from a python script and then load it in another one? Should I use other functions?
Thank you!

Comment: show the save commands.  Doesn't `pandas` have its own version of save and load?

Answer (score 14):

**TLDR;**

After hundreds of search and hours of debugging I found out that the issue was with git-lfs, my files did not get pulled using git-lfs.

```sh
git lfs install
git lfs pull
```

I think numpy needs to report this correctly

---

I had the exact same issue. `dtype` in my .npz file was `uint8`, so not an Object, technically allow_pickle should not be required. My numpy version is 1.20.x

Got the following when using `allow_pickle=False`

`ValueError: Cannot load file containing pickled data when allow_pickle=False`

And with `allow_pickle=True` I got

`OSError: Failed to interpret file 'finaldf_p_85_12.npy' as a pickle`

Comment: same thing happend to me. The .npy file was corrupted, I had to remake the repository to reupload the git lfs file (.npy and .kv)

Comment: Could somebody explain this more? I have been given a .npz file by someone else. I'm not sure what to do exactly. I don't understand how git has anything to do with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I used the syntax below to load the `.npy` file and it worked.

```py
np.load("finaldf_p_85_12.npy",allow_pickle=True)
```

I think you need to add `allow_pickle=True` parameter.

Comment: She already stated in her question, that this will prompt an `OSError` in her case.

Comment: Setting `allow_pickle=True` isn't necessarily going to work. In my case, it raised a `pickle.UnpicklingError` saying it could not interpret the file.

Answer (score 5):

The existing answers are all useful. Just a note that I just got this error from someone else's pickle file when the file itself was corrupted. As above, `allow_pickle=False` complained about pickle being disabled, and `allow_pickle=True` complained about it not being a valid pickle file. The fix was just redownloading the file in my case.

Comment: Indeed the best answer applying to my case

Answer (score 2):

Python uses a native data serialization module called Pickle. Nested data (like a list of lists) is serialized using pickle and NumPy warns against pickling.

> Warning:
> Loading files that contain object arrays uses the pickle module, which is not secure against erroneous or maliciously constructed data. Consider passing allow_pickle=False to load data that is known not to contain object arrays for the safer handling of untrusted sources.

You might be saving an array which consists a single dataFrame. This causes pickling.  Example:

```
x =  array([[ 0.1,  0.1,  0.1],
       [ 0.1,  0.1,  0.1],
       [ 0.1,  0.1,  0.1],
       [ 0.1,  0.1,  0.1],
       [ 0.1,  0.1,  0.1],
       [ 0.1,  0.1,  0.1],
       [ 0.1,  0.1,  0.1]])
```

In that case, try saving just the numpy array as `np.save(filename, x[0])`. This will not use any pickling to save your data and resolves the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I was dealing with the problem long time. I have tried all of the solutions which are listed here however they all didn't work. I have tried different versions of `python` such as `3.7, 2.7, 3.9` and the result was same.

Finally I have noticed that the file with the extension `.npy` is corrupted so it gives out this error. Here is the line giving the error.

```
npyFile = np.load('file1.npy')
```

So whoever come accross the same problem first of all it would be better to check the `.npy` file.

Comment: How do you check the .npy file if you can't load it?

Comment: it can be opened via on gedit

Answer (score 1):

The OSError suggests you could be having a python 2/python 3 issue. I had the same problem and errors when I was trying to read a file with python 3 that had been written in python 2.  For me, using the np.load command with the following arguments worked:

```
np.load('file.npy',allow_pickle=True,fix_imports=True,encoding='latin1')
```

The doc for numpy.load says about the encoding argument, "Only useful when loading Python 2 generated pickled files in Python 3, which includes npy/npz files containing object arrays."

Answer (score 1):

my hypothesis is when I am picking npz file, some other task is writing in that npz and in that case `np.load(file_path,mmap_mode='r')` gives 'Cannot load file containing pickled data when allow_pickle=False'.

So reading it after some time fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the file was corrupted. However this happened in some unexpected way that is why I post this here.

**TLDR**: calling `np.load` with wrong access mode can already corrupt your file so you need to export it again.

---

I started to save my file as usual:

```py
with open('data.npy', 'wb') as f:
    np.save(f, data)
```

In a different script I copy pasted the code and modified it to call load instead of save:

```py
with open('data.npy', 'wb') as f: # <-- wrong access mode 
    data = np.load(f)
```

Note that I forget to change the access mode! I got some `UnsupportedOperation` error and just corrected the access mode and didn't thought much of it first. The following attempt to load the file resulted in the error `ValueError: Cannot load file containing pickled data when allow_pickle=False` even when calling `np.load(data, allow_pickle=True)`. Everything works fine after saving the file again and this time using `np.load(data)` with the correct access code worked even without `allow_pickle=True`.

I didn't expect that this single `np.load` call with the wrong access mode would already corrupt my file. Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Everyone here is saying that the file might be corrupted but no one is explaining _why_. In my my case the data was very simple so I couldn't figure out why it was corrupted. My issue was exactly the same as this answer, reading the npy in write mode instead of read, which corrupted the file

Comment: This is a bit scary that a single typo could corrupt data in a potentially irreversible way...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Try `np.loadtxt` instead.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I uploaded my documents to drive and I uploaded the documents from the drive.
It is solved.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount("/content/drive")
label = np.load("path/labels.npy")
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case — and yes, this was a rather silly issue — I needed to do `np.loadtxt`, not `np.load`, as my file was a simple text file.

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html

Answer (score -1):

In my case, i met the same problem as you wrote in your question. I found that if the .npy file is empty (0 kb) , this error would occur. so maybe just check the .npy file.

Answer (score -2):

Just make sure the file isn't corrupted.

Comment: Please, give more information. Prefereably an example and a code section.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).