# Why is Azure ML jupyter notebook is not loading npy file?

Tags: python, azure, numpy, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

I have migrated my notebook from google colab to Azure ML since the computation was too intensive for the free GPUs provided by colab. However, running the notebook in azure ML gives the error
"Cannot load file containing pickled data when allow_pickle=False" for a **non pickled file.**

The code throwing the error is:

```
data_fname = 'airfoil_interp.npy' #name of the npy file loaded into the files of the workspace in Azure
X = np.load(data_fname) #1528 samples with 192 B-Spline interpolated points in x and y dimension
```

The error being shown:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0jW2.png)

Running the same code in Colab throws no error at all.
What is the reason for this and any way to fix this for Azure ML notebook?

PS I even changed allowed_pickle to True
It returned the following error:
"Failed to interpret file 'airfoil_interp.npy' as a pickle"

Answer (score 0):

The error should mostly go away by specifying `allow_pickle=True` as follows:

```
X = np.load('./file.npy', allow_pickle=True)
```

but if not, try passing the other available parameters as well:

```
np.load('./file.npy', allow_pickle=True, fix_imports=True, encoding='xxx')
```

If that doesn't help, do check the other workarounds mentioned in this similar SO post: [Cannot load file containing pickled data - Python .npy I/O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60191681/cannot-load-file-containing-pickled-data-python-npy-i-o)